# Can't upload files larger than 10MB via axios

Tags: axios

I am trying to send a file larger than 10MB (which is the default maximum) via axios.
This is my code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('files', this.file_xcode_ios);

                axios.post('/xcode_ios.php?timestamp=<?=$get_id;?>', formData, {
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
                  })
```

I am using this axios script (last version of axios 0.19.2)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

I have read about:

```
maxContentLength: Infinity,
maxBodyLength: Infinity
```

But I can't make it work.

I get this error:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me fix this.

Comment: I think issue might not be with axios or frontend and its with the backend...  Pls check ur php code

Comment: I did already. I thought that was the issue but I tested and it wasn't. Then I read that axios don't pass files larger than 10MB. That is why I am getting 413 error. I am trying to upload a file which doesn't exist because it's not being passed through axios. I know for a fact the issue is from axios.

Comment: try this without infinity, maxContentLength: 100000000,
        maxBodyLength: 1000000000

Comment: Glad it helped u.. I am posting it as answer accept it

Comment: What's the unit of these fields, bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some of the forums I came across using

```
maxContentLength: 10000000,
maxBodyLength: 10000000
```

instead of

```
maxContentLength: Infinity,
maxBodyLength: Infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

```
maxContentLength: 10000000,
maxBodyLength: 10000000
```

I implemented on axios but don't can make http request with successfully , continue with error

**Error [ERR_FR_MAX_BODY_LENGTH_EXCEEDED]: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit**

this is my code

```js
axios.post(url, bodyFormData,{
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                maxBodyLength: 10000000,
                maxContentLength: 10000000,
                emulateJSON: true
                
            })
```